# wget command to save output with user specified name using url input file

Tags: bash, wget

I am trying : 
1. wget -i url.txt 
and

2. wget -O output.ext

How do I join both? Download urls listed in url.txt and save them with the names I specify, as seperate files.

Comment: What about `wget -i url.txt -O output.ext`?

Comment: say I have url1.com url2.com and url3.com.
Now your suggested command will append all data from all three urls into one file, output.ext.
I need url1.com in url1.ext and so on

Answer (score 1):

Define all the URLs in url.txt and give this a try to see if this is what you need:

```
for url in $(cat url.txt); do wget $url -O $url.out ; done
```

If your URLs consist of one or more URIs, this would replace slash with underscore:

```
for url in $(cat url.txt); do wget $url -O $(echo $url | sed "s/\//_/g").out ; done
```

Comment: My url.txt has example.com/file1.jpg as a url.
With for url in $(cat url.txt); do wget $url -O $url.out ; done,
output give : "example.com/file1.jpg.out : no such file or directory"

Comment: @AbhishekSingh - see the updated answer to replace slash with underscore in the output filename, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In this situation, i think, you need two files with the same number of lines, to map each url with a corresponding name:

`url.txt` (source file containing your urls, example content given here):

```
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/click/trunk/examples/click-spring-cayenne/README.txt
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/click/trunk/examples/click-spring-cayenne/README.txt
```

`output_names.txt` (filenames you want to assign):

```
readme1.txt
readme2.txt
```

Then you iterate over both files and pass the contents to `wget`, e.g. with the following `script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a url < "$1"
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a output < "$2"
len=${#url[@]}
for ((i=0;i<$len;i++))
do
  wget "${url[$i]}" -O "${output[$i]}"
done
```

Call:

```
./script url.txt output_names.txt
```